# mypy type checking for variables that are indirectly declared in later `elif`

Tags: python, mypy

Consider the following code, in which a variable `x` is referenced before it is declared. When it is declared, it is declared indirectly from `y`.

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i < 3:
        state = 'earlier'
    elif i < 7:
        state = 'middle'
    else:
        state = 'later'
    # do actions based on state
    if state == 'later':
        print(x)
    elif state == 'middle':
        x = y
        print(y)
    elif state == 'earlier':
        y = 2
```

`mypy` gives the following error for this code:

```sh
$ mypy stackoverflow.py
stackoverflow.py:10: error: Cannot determine type of 'x'
```

How can I appropriately annotate this code so that `mypy` can correctly determine the type of `x`?

My question is *not* how to refactor the code. I know that things like changing the order of the `if state == ...` blocks would fix the problem, but I need to keep them in the current order for various reasons. The question is how to make `mypy` figure out types when given this structure.

Comment: Python doesn't have declarations, only assignments. The problem is that `mypy`, a *static* code analyzer, cannot tell that `state == 'earlier'` will be true exclusively before `state == 'middle'` is true.

Comment: What performance are you concerned about? The only thing performance-related that changing the order of this code would do is change the number of times that `state` is compared to a value, and right now you are *maximizing* the number of comparisons that will be made.

Comment: And finally, what would change if you abandoned `state` altogether and replaced those comparisons with `i < 3`, `3 < i < 7` and `7 < i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just declare it first with some value good for initialization? Like you do with static typed languages like C.

Comment: This is a great idea. After a little poking around in the PEPs, I found out that you can even declare a type without initializing: `a: str` instead of `a = ''`. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#global-and-local-variable-annotations

Answer (score 0):

I would break this loop into 3 separate loops, for clarity if for no other reason.

```
for i in range(3):
    y = 2

for i in range(3,7):
    x = y
    print(y)

for i in range(7,10):
    print(x)
```

This eliminates the need for `state` altogether, as now the order of the loops themselves determines what state you are in.

An alternate method, if you don't like the hard-coded endpoints and would rather refer to interval sizes instead:

```
from itertools import islice

itr = iter(range(10))

for i in islice(itr, 3):
    y = 2

for i in islice(itr, 4):
    x = y
    print(y)

for i in itr:
    print(x)
```

Comment: This is a great idea for my toy example, but not for my actual problem. I should have been more explicit in the OP that this is a parser, so it is iterating over lines in an input file, and it goes back and forth between "states".